# how do external website redirects to localhost

Tags: javascript, http, localhost

I was just testing a `oAuth2` service and give the callback (redirect) url to `http://localhost:8000/outh-login`, first I moved to auth website and then after a successful login I redirected back to callback url with token.

It worked as it should be but wait how can a external website able to redirect on localhost from internet ?

Can someone tell me how it is actually working, I am really curious.

May be using javascript ?

Can js redirect to localhost ?

I am not sure how it is working so if someone who knows, tell me.

Comment: The external website simply issues a `Location: http://localhost:8000/oauth-login` response header which the client (your browser) receives and acts on. Since your browser can reach `localhost`, there's no problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not really the website that does the 'redirecting', it's your browser. When redirecting there's no communication between where you came from, and where you are going to.

The server tells the browser: "Open this url", and that looks like a HTTP header, for example:

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Location: http://localhost:8000/
```